# How to write Test case for uniqueness with Scope in Rails Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I want to write RSpec test for this validation but it always give me error

```
validates :post_id, uniqueness: { scope: :user_id }
```

I am using this solution but it is not working

```
it { is_expected.to validate_uniqueness_of(:post_id).scoped_to(:user_id, :created_at) }
```

Error

```
Like is expected to validate that :post_id is case-sensitively unique within the scope of :user_id and :created_at
  Failure/Error: it { is_expected.to validate_uniqueness_of(:post_id).scoped_to(:user_id, :created_at) }

    Expected Like to validate that :post_id is case-sensitively unique
    within the scope of :user_id and :created_at, but this could not be
    proved.
      Expected the validation to be scoped to :user_id and :created_at, but
      it was scoped to :user_id instead.
```

Any help

Comment: Your scope is only scoped to `:user_id`, but the spec expects it to be scope to `:user_id` and `:created_at`...

Comment: So How I can fix it

Comment: Add `created_at` to your scope or remove `created_at` from your spec. It really depends on what is the correct way of validating the data in the domain.

Answer (score 1):

If in model you have

```
validates :post_id, uniqueness: { scope: :user_id }
```

then you need in specs

```
it { is_expected.to validate_uniqueness_of(:post_id).scoped_to(:user_id) }
```

or

```
it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:post_id).scoped_to(:user_id) }
```